# How do I name all these telemetrics sound effects?

Tags: sfx, file-naming, archiving

I've been doing a bunch of recordings of machinery and computers using an induction microphone. I'm having a really hard time naming the files because they don't sound like anything I have a point of reference to. A lot of these files sound similar but like different pitched variations, which also makes it difficult to archive properly.

Here are two examples of the recordings:

https://soundcloud.com/kaiwolf26/induction-recording-1

https://soundcloud.com/kaiwolf26/induction-recording-2

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest naming them after the object that is the sound source for the recording. In the metadata you can then get descriptive and just add anything that would help you find them later into the keywords but as the main name I'd stick with source and other relevant details (e.g. induction_harddrive_writing_... or shorter ind_hd_writing ...).

Answer (score 2):

What André said.
Then try describing what you HEAR. Buzz, hiss, whirr, growl, whine. You're basically putting keywords into the filename - good practice in my opinion.

If I was a sound editor/designer looking for buzzy, whiny electronic sounds, I would search my database for some of those adjectives first, unless i knew I had just the right recording of a harddrive going off the rails.